# CompletableFuture always throw time out exception

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have a piece of code like below

```java
protected List<AMQMessage> waitForReceivedRawMessageFromActiveMq(AMQConsumerMessageListener listener) {
CompletableFuture<List<AMQMessage>> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    while (listener.getMessageList().isEmpty()) {}
    return listener.getMessageList();
});
List<AMQMessage> rawMessage = Lists.newLinkedList();
try {
    rawMessage = completableFuture.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return rawMessage;
}
```

It always throws `TimeoutException`, I don't know what's happening.
But when I have toggled debug point in IDEA, it work.
Is there anyone can explain for me, pleaseeee.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the debugger?

Comment: I add debug point in line ```return listener.getMessageList();``` and above code work fine.

Comment: What *exactly* do you do. You put a breakpoint at that line, debug your program. Then is the breakpoint hit?

Comment: that's right. But when I turn off breakpoint, the above code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: what is `AMQConsumerMessageListener`? this question as it is right now makes no sense, voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of insufficient synchronization. You are updating the `listener`'s `messageList` in some thread, but the thread that is running your `supplyAsync()` (the `ForkJoin` commonPool's worker thread by default) doesn't see that change, and so the `while` loop runs forever. Sometimes it *may* see that change, but it's not guaranteed. Perhaps the debugger handles memory *visibility* of threads differently.

**Solution**: Try adding `synchronized` to your `getMessageList()` and `setMessageList()` methods. And/or use a synchronized list (like `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, etc.), depending on whether you are updating the reference of the list variable, or updating its contents.

Comment: Can you share me an article about it. I actually have no idea about their mechanism

Comment: you might be right, but without knowing what `AMQConsumerMessageListener` is or does, you can not simply assume that adding synchronized to those methods (which is probably far too much anyway, a `volatile` read/write in proper place would be enough) would do the correct thing.